# How do I delete a row from a gridview and SQL using a webservice?

Tags: c#, sql-server, webservice-client

I want to be able to delete a row from a gridview when I click on a delete button. But for some reason, the code only deletes the rows from the gridview but not the from the SQL DataBase.

It's because i'm not using the web method eliminarTarea correctly?

What am I doing wrong? Many Thanks!

button method

```
            try
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("¿Está seguro de querer eliminar esta nota?","Message",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    int rows = DataGVTareas.RowCount;
                    for(int i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        if (DataGVTareas.Rows[i].Selected) 
                        {
                            ServiceMantenedorCliente.WebServiceMantenedorClienteSoapClient auxNegocio = new ServiceMantenedorCliente.WebServiceMantenedorClienteSoapClient();
                            auxNegocio.webEliminarTarea(titulotareasDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ToString());
                            tareasBindingSource.RemoveAt(DataGVTareas.Rows[i].Index);
                        }
                    }
                     

                    
                }
                //ServiceMantenedorCliente.WebServiceMantenedorClienteSoapClient auxNegocio = new ServiceMantenedorCliente.WebServiceMantenedorClienteSoapClient();
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DataGVTareas.ToString()))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No hay datos por eliminar ", "NoteIt", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                }
                else
                {
                    //auxNegocio.webEliminarCliente(DataGVTareas.Rows[i]);
                    
                    MessageBox.Show("Los datos han sido eliminados", "NoteIt", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Se ha producido un error inesperado, por favor reinicie la aplicación e intente nuevamente" + ex.Message, "NoteIt", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

app code

```
        public void eliminarTarea(String titulo_tareas)
        {
            this.ConexionTareas();
            this.Conec1.CadenaSQL = "DELETE FROM " + this.Conec1.NombreTabla
                                    + " WHERE titulo_tareas = '" + titulo_tareas + "';";
            this.Conec1.EsSelect = false;
            this.Conec1.Conectar();
        }
```

webservice method

```
        [WebMethod]
        public void webEliminarTarea(String titulo_tareas)
        {
            NegocioNotas auxNegocio = new NegocioNotas();
            auxNegocio.eliminarCliente(titulo_tareas);
        }
```

Comment: Is that meant to be 1 code block or 7 (of which one is completely blank)? Your 4th code block looks like it's wide open to injection attacks; a significant and fatal security vulnerability.

Comment: @Larnu my bad, first time asking, t's was meant to be 3 code blocks, and I only have problems with the button method

Comment: Having such a large security vulnerability is certainly a problem too.

Comment: @Larnu it's just a college project, they only ask me for the app to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't read spanish so I hope I get the gist of how your controls are wired up... where do you call the `.EndEdit()` for the [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/bindingsource-component-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) which actually writes back to the database?

Also, as @Larnu mentioned, fix your SQL query:

```
public void eliminarTarea(String titulo_tareas)
{
    this.ConexionTareas();

    //You'll have to fix this up because I don't know what "Conec1" is.
    //This demonstrates putting your text values into a parameter instead
    //of string concatenation.
    //Concatenation of NombreTabla is also a vulnerability but I don't know how to fix that one 
    //because it is a table name and I don't know where NobreTabla is sourced from.
    string sqlTxt = "DELETE FROM " + this.Conec1.NombreTabla
        + " WHERE titulo_tareas = @TituloTareas;";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand([sqlConnection here], sqlTxt);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TituloTareas", titulo_tareas);
    this.Conec1.SqlCommand = cmd;  //Does this even work with Conec1?

    this.Conec1.EsSelect = false;
    this.Conec1.Conectar();
}
```

Comment: nombretabla comes from a public class called ConnectionSQL, where I store all the methods that have to do with connecting to the DataBase, and I use Conec1 as an object of that clase. What I want to do, it's to use the webmethod "webEliminarTarea" to delete both gridview's and SQL rows.